# <div width="100%"></div>内で、できるだけ大きくSVG表示したい時のviewBox属性の設定は？

Tags: css, svg

やりたいこと
`<div width="100%"></div>`内で、(画面の大きさに合わせて)できるだけ大きくSVG表示したい。
width="100%"内なので、SVGに大きさの固定数値を指定したくない。
縦横比は可変してもよい。

---

追記

下記のような感じですか？
svgタグ自体には width や height や viewBox属性を別に指定しなくてもよいのですか？

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <svg>
        <!-- ここにSVGの内容を記述 -->
    </svg>
</div>
```

---

追記 2
rectタグをできるだけ緑色の範囲まで大きく表示させたいのですが、rect タグのx位置やy位置は固定ですか？ widthも100%にはならないのですか？
縦横比は可変でもよいと思い、試しに`<svg preserveAspectRatio="none">`へ変更してみましたが、表示は何も変わりませんでした。

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%;background-color:green;">
  <svg>
    <rect x="42.597706" y="42.440388" style="fill:#d6eaff;" width="1598.741699" height="2298.899414"></rect> 
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: 関連するコードも質問に含めてください。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`viewBox` は SVG の座標系の中でどの部分を見せるかを指定するもので、静止画ならたいてい固定の値を書きます。デフォルトのサイズや縦横比に影響はありますが、HTMLページ中の表示される大きさを変更するためのものであはりません。
HTMLページ中での大きさを指定するのは `<img>` と大体同じで、`width` 属性、`height` 属性、`width` CSS プロパティ、`height` CSS プロパティなどです。

`viewBox` を適切に指定して、`<svg>` に `width` や `height` などを指定しなければ使える広さいっぱいに広がると思います。
`viewBox` 指定がないと HTML ページ中では 300x150 というサイズになります。

(もしそうならないなら、具体的なコードで質問してください)

追記:
`<rect>` がちょうどおさまるような `viewBox` を指定するだけでいいです。

```html
<div style="width: 100%;background-color:green;">
  <svg viewBox="42.597706 42.440388 1598.741699 2298.899414">
    <rect x="42.597706" y="42.440388" style="fill:#d6eaff;" width="1598.741699" height="2298.899414"></rect> 
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: 疑問点を質問本文に追記しました

Comment: 試した結果どうだったのですか? 期待どおりにならなかったのでしょうか?

Comment: 試してみたのですが、期待通り表示されませんでした。svgタグの中に<rect x="42.597706" y="42.440388" style="fill:#d6eaff;" width="1598.741699" height="2298.899414"></rect>タグがあり、この範囲に表示が依存しているような印象を受けました。

Comment: 再現できる具体的なコードで質問するようお願いします。ちょっと回答の文面を更新します。

Comment: viewBox 指定がないと HTML ページ中では 確かに 300x150 というサイズになりました。viewBox には固定値以外も指定できますか？ 簡易具体例コードを質問本文に追記しました

Comment: 期待した通り動作したのですが、rectの「x」「y」「width」「height」属性にどんな値が入っても、期待した通り普遍的に動作するような方法がもしあれば知りたいのですが……

Comment: JavaScriptを使わないと無理だと思います。
こうやってあとから条件が出てくると回答の手間が増えるので、初めからすべての情報を出して質問していただけると助かります。

Comment: 「JavaScriptを使わないと無理」。質問時点では、CSSでレスポンシブみたいに設定できるのかと、思っていました。大変参考になりました